# How to fill/complete null/zero cells with a fixed number in an Excel table?

Tags: excel

I have a table with some null/zero cells of a column.

I would like to replace the null/zero value with a fixed number such as 9999. Is there an automated way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried using the replace function? Otherwise VBA will be your best bet.

Comment: What is null for you? a missing value or an empty cell? Or is it really "null" literally?

Comment: use this formula =IF(OR(A1="", A1=0), 9999,A1) 
Replace your A1 with your cell reference and repeat this formula for the column. Or you can just use VA like VBA Pete says

Comment: Why not just Find/Replace? What have you tried so far? Find `""` replace "9999"?

Comment: Thank you all, I needed to know the correct function because I am uninformed. I have blank cells and I used Go To Special to selected them and then I replaced them with the value I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If its all about Zero and Null then Try following formula

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(E2)),"9999")
```

You can use any other formula by replacing E2 with your formula

Or you can use Custom Formatting, Select your Table Column, Press CTRL+1 Or Go to Custom Formatting and Click on Custom at the bottom of appeared window and in the custom bar put this format

```
0;-0;9999;"9999"
```

Hope it works for you